# Building and running a Java Selenium Automation on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, github

I created an automation in Java that utilizes Selenium, ChromeDriver, and the JExcelApi. In order to simplify the distribution of this automation, I am attempting to add it to a Jenkins server (see more details from my previous [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862007/is-it-possible-to-build-a-web-automation-that-can-run-through-a-browser/57914012#57914012)).

I have configured a Freestyle project on Jenkins that uses GitHub for its source code management. For the build environment preferences, I selected:

```
Delete workspace before build starts
```

Finally, selecting "Build Now" for this project executes the following shell:

```
javac src/GUI.java
java GUI
```

When building the program on Jenkins, I am getting a variety of errors. First, the output says that my packages do not exist. Additionally, I am getting a variety of "cannot find symbol" errors. Finally, I am getting errors that say that a local variable cannot be accessed from within an inner class. Here is the detailed console output from Jenkins:

```
+ javac src/GUI.java
src/GUI.java:12: error: package Objects does not exist
import Objects.Product;
              ^
src/GUI.java:13: error: package Reader does not exist
import Reader.ReadExcel;
             ^
src/GUI.java:14: error: package Reader does not exist
import Reader.WriteExcel;
             ^
src/GUI.java:15: error: package co.mitch.selenium.runner does not exist
import co.mitch.selenium.runner.ActiveIQ;
                               ^
src/GUI.java:16: error: package co.mitch.selenium.runner does not exist
import co.mitch.selenium.runner.Ascend;
                               ^
src/GUI.java:17: error: package co.mitch.selenium.runner does not exist
import co.mitch.selenium.runner.LinkedIn;
                               ^
src/GUI.java:18: error: package jxl.read.biff does not exist
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
                    ^
src/GUI.java:19: error: package jxl.write does not exist
import jxl.write.WriteException;
                ^
src/GUI.java:20: error: package jxl.write.biff does not exist
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
                     ^
src/GUI.java:395: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void performCreateWatchlist() throws BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class BiffException
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:440: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void performGetContactInformation(String username, String password, String path) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, HeadlessException, WriteException {
                                                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class BiffException
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:440: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void performGetContactInformation(String username, String password, String path) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, HeadlessException, WriteException {
                                                                                                                                                            ^
  symbol:   class RowsExceededException
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:440: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void performGetContactInformation(String username, String password, String path) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, HeadlessException, WriteException {
                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   class WriteException
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:91: error: local variable menuLabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(menuLabel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:92: error: local variable centerPanel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(centerPanel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:103: error: local variable menuLabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(menuLabel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:104: error: local variable centerPanel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(centerPanel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:115: error: local variable menuLabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(menuLabel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:116: error: local variable centerPanel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                frame.remove(centerPanel);
                             ^
src/GUI.java:182: error: local variable usernameField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                username = usernameField.getText(); 
                           ^
src/GUI.java:183: error: local variable passwordField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                password = passwordField.getText(); 
                           ^
src/GUI.java:184: error: local variable nameField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                watchlistName = nameField.getText(); 
                                ^
src/GUI.java:185: error: local variable excelField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                excelPath = excelField.getText(); 
                            ^
src/GUI.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
                } catch (BiffException | IOException | InterruptedException e2) {
                         ^
  symbol: class BiffException
src/GUI.java:252: error: local variable usernameField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                username = usernameField.getText(); 
                           ^
src/GUI.java:253: error: local variable passwordField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                password = passwordField.getText(); 
                           ^
src/GUI.java:254: error: local variable excelField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                excelPath = excelField.getText(); 
                            ^
src/GUI.java:261: error: cannot find symbol
                } catch (RowsExceededException e1) {
                         ^
  symbol: class RowsExceededException
src/GUI.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
                } catch (BiffException e1) {
                         ^
  symbol: class BiffException
src/GUI.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
                } catch (WriteException e1) {
                         ^
  symbol: class WriteException
src/GUI.java:331: error: local variable usernameField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                    performLinkedInHelp(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getText());
                                        ^
src/GUI.java:331: error: local variable passwordField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                    performLinkedInHelp(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getText());
                                                                 ^
src/GUI.java:396: error: cannot find symbol
        ActiveIQ activeIQUser = new ActiveIQ();
        ^
  symbol:   class ActiveIQ
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:396: error: cannot find symbol
        ActiveIQ activeIQUser = new ActiveIQ();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ActiveIQ
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:399: error: cannot find symbol
        ReadExcel excelReader = new ReadExcel(excelPath);
        ^
  symbol:   class ReadExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:399: error: cannot find symbol
        ReadExcel excelReader = new ReadExcel(excelPath);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ReadExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:446: error: cannot find symbol
        ReadExcel excelReader = new ReadExcel(excelPath);
        ^
  symbol:   class ReadExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:446: error: cannot find symbol
        ReadExcel excelReader = new ReadExcel(excelPath);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ReadExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:450: error: cannot find symbol
        Ascend run = new Ascend(); 
        ^
  symbol:   class Ascend
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:450: error: cannot find symbol
        Ascend run = new Ascend(); 
                         ^
  symbol:   class Ascend
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:470: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Product> output = new ArrayList<Product>(); 
                  ^
  symbol:   class Product
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:470: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Product> output = new ArrayList<Product>(); 
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Product
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:493: error: cannot find symbol
        WriteExcel writer = new WriteExcel(); 
        ^
  symbol:   class WriteExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:493: error: cannot find symbol
        WriteExcel writer = new WriteExcel(); 
                                ^
  symbol:   class WriteExcel
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:509: error: cannot find symbol
        LinkedIn run = new LinkedIn(); 
        ^
  symbol:   class LinkedIn
  location: class GUI
src/GUI.java:509: error: cannot find symbol
        LinkedIn run = new LinkedIn(); 
                           ^
  symbol:   class LinkedIn
  location: class GUI
Note: src/GUI.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
46 errors
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

From my research, I found that one possible solution would be to use a Maven project. However, I do not have any experience with Maven so this would be a difficult process. Is there a different shell command that I should use to make this build and run properly? I attempted to compile each source code file individually but that also returned errors:

```
javac src/Objects/Product.java
javac src/Reader/ReadExcel.java
javac src/Reader/WriteExcel.java
javac src/co/mitch/selenium/runnuer/ActiveIQ.java
javac src/co/mitch/selenium/runner/Ascend.java
javac src/co/mitch/selenium/running/LinkedIn.java
javac src/GUI.java
java GUI
```

If there is no way to make this work with a different shell command, what options do I have to get the automation to run correctly on the server? Thanks in advance for any help that you are able to provide.

Comment: Is Jenkins running on a Linux or windows server? I know on Windows it runs as a Windows service which had no desktop available, and thus no GUI will run.

Comment: I did not set up the Jenkins server since it is a corporate environment so I do not know the answer. Is there a place on Jenkins that I can check?